# Select inner text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="boxen checkedzahlen" id="box41_0_1">
 41
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="cb41_0_1" id="cb41_0_1" checked="checked"/>
</div>
```

Something like this is given, how can I animate the text `41`, if `$(this)` (the class `boxen`) is clicked?

`this > *` doesn't work. Neither does `this:children`.

Comment: You need to work on that question. Please post some source code and describe the missing parts. Beside that, on jquery.com, there are examples for such basic things (if I understand you right)

Comment: thx, but didn't get the information from the home of "JQuery" ;)
the problem is how you select a text .. at the last dom level.
if there would be a span .. no problem.

Comment: $('.boxen').click(function () { 
    if ($(this).hasClass("hello")){
    $(this).removeClass("hello");
    }
    else{
    $("this > *").animate({
     zIndex: "10",
     fontSize: "28px"
    },600).animate({
     fontSize: "9px",
     textAlign: "center",
     zIndex: "0"
    }); 
 $(this).addClass("hello");
    }
});

Comment: how can i turn on syntax highlighting ?

Comment: You still need to clarify. Is the problem that you can't select "41" without also selecting the checkbox?

Comment: @Sven: You can't do it in a comment.

Answer (score 36):

Because of the slightly confusing title, some people (like me) may be coming to this question looking for how to get the *textual content* of a DOM element. You can accomplish this by:

```
$("#myselector").text() // returns the content of the element as plain text
```

Comment: No I mean I felt exactly the same 'Because of the slightly confusing title'

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment and not a solution?

Answer (score 5):

$("#divID").html() would get the text inside.

Comment: $("#divID").html().animate({ .. .

?

Comment: After 3 hours of trying to figure this out and numerous confusing overloads and method names, your answer saved me sanity.

Answer (score 2):

In order to select the div, you would use the following:

```
$('#box41_0_1')
```

In order to animate the whole box, you could do

```
$('#box41_0_1').fadeOut().fadeIn();
```

or some other [animation effect](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects).

**Edit:** If you want to select only the inner text, you could try [wrapping](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapInner#html) the inner text with a div, but with the code you provided, that would also select the checkbox I believe. Code example:

```
$('#box41_0_1').wrapInner("<span id='span41_0_1'></span>");
$('#span41_0_1').fadeOut().fadeIn();
```

Comment: it's not the problem to select the box, or how to animate it.
the problem is, just to get the z-Index on the "41".
-> the text inside the div, if i animate the whole thing, things like the border also get the new zIndex.

Comment: If you're only looking to select the z-index, "41" will have the same z-index as its parent div.

Comment: thats the problem.. i just want to set the zindex to the numbers..
without printing a span arround..

Comment: @Sven I don't believe that is possible. I think you can only set the z-index of an actual element, not it's text.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the contents of the div in a span and then move the input outside of that span. Then you can animate the span. Something like this:

```
$('.boxen').each(function() {
  var $thisBox = $(this);
  $thisBox.wrapInner('<span></span>');
  $thisBox.find('input').appendTo($thisBox);
});

$('.boxen span').animate({fontSize: '28px'}, 400);
```

You could also mix and match straight DOM scripting with jQuery, like so:

```
$('.boxen').each(function() {
  var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
  newSpan.innerHTML = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
  this.firstChild.nodeValue = '';
  $(this).prepend(newSpan);
});

$('.boxen span').animate({fontSize: '28px'}, 400);
```

Either way should work.