# Get value of element on which the event fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select inner text (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644342/select-inner-text-jquery)

I have a span:

```
<span class="test"> target_string </span>
```

And the event, that is fired on click on any element of the page.

```
$('body').click(function(event){
  if ($(event.target).attr('class') == 'test'){
    alert(???);
  }
}
```

How can I obtain target_string value?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `$(event.target).text()` to get the text.

Comment: @zerkms Because `$(this)` would refer to the body.

Comment: @zerkms: The event is bound to `'body'`.  `this` would be `'body'`, not the clicked element.

Comment: @zerkms $(this) would refer to the body element being clicked, not the event.target.

Comment: thanks - i needed to use val() instead of text(), but this lead me in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

Possibly more efficient to delegate from the body:

```
$('body').on('click', '.test', function(event){
    alert($(this).text())
});
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, that may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

```
$('body').click(function(event){
  var $targ = $(event.target);
  if ($targ.hasClass('test')){
    alert($targ.text());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you plan to work with other elements inside that event handler besides those with a class of test, but this may be more concise:

```
$('.test').click(function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```