# how to use jquery to get value out of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the contents of a div using Jquery.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="DataRow" data-vendorid="67">
    <div class="DataColumn" style="width: 60%;">
        Barracuda
    </div>
    <div class="DataColumn" style="width: 20%; text-align: center;">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="DataColumn" style="width: 20%; text-align: center;">
        2
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.DataRow').click(function () {
        // get value: Barracuda 
    });
});
```

Comment: There are 3 div's inside `.DataRow` div. Do you want to get the first div value? If you want Barracuda, you can use :first on children and get it .text()

Comment: Has all been answered already: [How to find an element within an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386100/how-to-find-an-element-within-an-element). The jQuery [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) contain information about all the methods you can use to find a certain element. Then have a look at [Select inner text (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644342/select-inner-text-jquery).

Comment: I felt this was a duplicate at first too, but given that he doesn't have a unique class on the sub-div's, I think this a tricky question for a JQuery beginner, and not immediately apparent on how to solve / what keywords to zero in on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('.DataRow').click(function () {
        alert($(this).find(':first-child').text());
    });
});
```

Or:

```
$(function () {
    $('.DataRow').click(function () {
        alert($(this).children().first().text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get content of the clicked div it might help you.

```
$(function () {
    $('.DataRow').click(function (event) {

        alert(event.target.innerHTML);
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/95Cab/)

If you need to get only the first value:

```
$('.DataRow').click(function () {
    var first = $(this).children().eq(0).html();
    alert(first);
});​
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/95Cab/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get only "Baracuda", i.e. first div text, you could use innerHTML like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.DataRow').click(function () {
        // get value: Barracuda 
        alert($(this).children("div")[0].innerHTML);
    });
});​
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZemdY/).

Comment: Your example in the URL is absolutely wrong. Please modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this:

```
var value=$(".DataColumn").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the contents of the *first* child:

```
$('.DataRow').click(function () {
    var first = $(this).children(":first").html();
});
```

To get the contents of the *third* child:

```
$('.DataRow').click(function () {
    var third = $(this).children(":eq(2)").html();
});
```